# Is there a "select all" option in WP8

Tags: apps, lumia, functionality

I use Lumia 820 with WP8. I use MS word in its office app. I would like to know if there is a "select All" option in the windows phone 8. Just like `ctrl + A` in Windows desktop.

Comment: I've Benn looking since I got my phone 18 months ago. It wouldn't Arf be useful.
My phones a Lumia820 running Win 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is to tap the first word and then drag the second market to the end of the document... other then that... I don't see something like this